# Kotlin .add overriding all items of list in MutableList

Tags: object, kotlin, mutablelist

I have an object which contains a Mutable List

```
object TrackingEventsList {
    var EventDate: String = ""
    var EventDescription: String = ""
}

object Waybill {
    var WaybillNumber: String = ""
    var OriginHub: String = ""
    var TrackingEvents: MutableList<TrackingEventsList> = ArrayList()
}
```

When I try to add Waybill.TrackingEvents all previous instances are overwritten to and duplicate the last TrackingEvent added.

```
private fun fillTracking(events: NodeList) {
    var list = TrackingEventsList
    for (x: Int in 0 until events.length) {
        var tName = (events.item(x) as Element).tagName
        var event = (events.item(x).firstChild as Text).wholeText
        if (tName == "EventDate") {
            list.EventDate = event
        }
        if (tName == "EventDescription") {
            list.EventDescription = event
        }
    }
    Waybill.TrackingEvents.plus(list)
}
```

The result after calling fillTracking 3 times:

```
Waybill.TrackingEvents[0].EventDescription = "Event3"
Waybill.TrackingEvents[1].EventDescription = "Event3"
Waybill.TrackingEvents[2].EventDescription = "Event3"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`object` in Kotlin is a singleton, which means you can't initialize it, and it only has one instance globally. So when you change the items of a single instance, you will override the previous data.

You should change both of them (or at least TrackingEventsList) to `class` instead. If `Waybill`'s variables are instance-sensitive, it needs to be a class too. But in the code you added, I couldn't find anything that would say you use it as a singleton, so I left it as one.

```
class TrackingEventsList (
        var eventDate: String = "",
        var eventDescription: String = "")

/**
 * Also want to point out that this is still a singleton. If the data inside is instance-specific, you need to change it 
 * to a class. 
 */
object Waybill {
    var waybillNumber: String = ""
    var originHum: String = ""
    var trackingEvents: MutableList<TrackingEventsList> = ArrayList()
}

private fun fillTracking(events: NodeList) {
    val item = TrackingEventsList()
    for (x: Int in 0 until events.length) {
        var tName = (events.item(x) as Element).tagName
        var event = (events.item(x).firstChild as Text).wholeText

        if (tName == "EventDate") {
            item.eventDate = event
        }
        if (tName == "EventDescription") {
            item.eventDescription = event
        }
    }

    Waybill.trackingEvents.add(item)
}
```

And you should look into the naming conventions for Kotlin; fields never start with an upper-case letter, unless it's a static constant (in which case it's all-upper)

Comment: thanks ! when I change to start with a lower-case Android Studio advises me that Class name 'waybill' should start with an uppercase letter.

Just so I'm clear as I am quite new to Kotlin, If I change Waybill to be a class then I would need to initialize it and pass it from Fragment to Fragment?

Comment: @CraigP I said fields, not classes. Classes, interfaces, objects, and enums, should start with an upper-case letter. Fields (var and val) should start with a lower-case letter unless it's static and constant

Comment: The full style guide/coding convention list for Kotlin can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html

Comment: It looks like _both_ of these should be classes, not objects, FWIW.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thought so too, but without seeing more use of Waybill, I based my code on it being designed to be a singleton. Still did include that part though (that it should be a class too, if the fields are instance-sensitive)

Answer (score 5):

Since `TrackingEventsList` is an object, it means it's a singleton (or only has a single instance.)  When you go through your loop, you're always updating the same instance of your `TrackingEventsList` object.

Change `TrackingEventsList` to be this:

```
data class TrackingEventsList(var eventDate: String, var eventDescription: String)
```

Create a new instance each time you go through your loop, and then add it to your list at the end:

```
private fun fillTracking(events: NodeList) {
    var eventDate: String = ""
    var eventDescription: String = ""
    for (x: Int in 0 until events.length) {
        val tName = (events.item(x) as Element).tagName
        val event = (events.item(x).firstChild as Text).wholeText
        if (tName == "EventDate") {
            eventDate = event
        }
        if (tName == "EventDescription") {
            eventDescription = event
        }
    }
    Waybill.TrackingEvents.plus(TrackingEventsList(eventDate, eventDescription))
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is the difference between a class and data class?

Comment: Data classes automatically add some useful functions and has a few extra restrictions.  When you create a class just to hold some values, a data class is a great option.

More info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated